# Car, jets and bikes card games

Tags: identify-this-game

When I was a kid, I played these games with cards that came in a set, for example:

- Sports cars
- Luxury cars
- Jets
- Trains

and so forth.

Each set had some properties, for example, the cars had properties like:

- Torque
- Max speed
- 0-60
- Weight
- Length
- ...

We then held these cards in our grubby little paws, and took the top one. We chose a property that was considered good for our chosen card, and asked others to compare their top card's property by the same name. The winner then took all the cards, and started the next round, until someone won the game, landing up with all the cards.

I have two questions:

- What were these games called? I do not know what to Google for.
- Are these games still found on the market?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of searches, I finally figured out they are called "Top Trump Cards".

http://www.toptrumps.com (site appears to be down, from my side, though)

But it does appear that I have either recalled the rules incorrectly, or we made our own rules when we were kids (latter is the most probable).

I also found out where I could buy them in South Africa (where I live):

https://www.takealot.com/all?filter=Brand:Top+Trumps